# Swift: Convert Dates to elapsed and remaining time string

Tags: ios, swift, date

I have a Current, Start Date, and End Date. How can I convert these dates to elapsed and remaining time format using Swift?

The format needed is 00:00:00 (hours: minutes: seconds)

Currently, I get elapsed and remaining strings using the below code.

The code returns incorrectly to the Time I see in the Simulator.

**Example**: If the simulator time changes to 2:45 pm
My elapsed time's second is ahead (10s) of the actual seconds shown.
And the remaining seconds shows ahead for (9s)

I am getting like this

elapsed = 01:30:10, rem = 12:30:09

Can you help me fix the code or a simpler way to get the format I want correctly?

Code:

```
{
    let currDate = Date();

    let startDate = currDate;
    let endDate: Date = startDate.addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(minutes * 60));

    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(callback),  userInfo: nil, repeats: true);

}

@objc func Callback() {

    let time = dateToTimerString(currDate: currDate, startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate );
    NSLog( "Elapsed %@, Rem %@", time.elapsed, time.remaining );
}

func dateToTimerString(currDate: Date, startDate: Date, endDate: Date) -> (elapsed: String, remaining: String) {
    
    let elapsedTime: TimeInterval = currDate.timeIntervalSince(startDate);
    let remainingTime: TimeInterval = endDate.timeIntervalSince(currDate);
    
    let elapsedString = format(duration: elapsedTime);
    let remainingString = format(duration: remainingTime);
    
    return (elapsedString, remainingString);
}

func format(duration: TimeInterval) -> String {
    let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
    formatter.unitsStyle = .positional
    formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad

    return formatter.string(from: duration)!
}
```

Comment: Check out `RelativeDateTimeFormatter`

Comment: Also, are you using a Timer to update the time frequently?  Show that code

Comment: Yes I update the timer frequently. Called every one second,

Comment: You definitely want to run the timer faster than once per second. `Timer` isn't very accurate over longer durations and suffers from jitter. I would suggest every 0.2 seconds will give smoother output. And definitely look at RelativeDateTimeFormatter

Comment: @DávidPásztor I will check out what you said.

Comment: @Paulw11 will give a try on what you said

Answer (score 2):

There is an API for that: [`DateComponentsFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponentsformatter)

```
let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.unitsStyle = .positional
formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad

let elapsedString = formatter.string(from: elapsedTime)
let remainingString = formatter.string(from: remainingTime)
```

Comment: This was better than what I had. Thanks. 

I still have a problem when I print the log. The elapsed and remaining time not matching, like there is 1 sec delay between the two time.

Answer (score 0):

It actually works with the exact date and time that you are creating with that current date constant. And if you are changing string to date from dateformatter then you need to check if you are getting the exact value there after changing.

Comment: HI, I didn't change from string to date. What I have is a button. When I tap I get the current date, start date, and calculate the end time adding minutes.  
let date: Date = startDate.addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(minutes * 60));

Comment: Can you share the complete code. We would be able to help you in better way then

Comment: I have edited and give the code.